# How to send boolean as a json body in rest-assured

Tags: java, automated-tests, rest-assured

I have a PUT service where the request body is either true or false. The service is working fine in Postman with Content-Type as application/json. But it is failing when I try the same with Rest-Assured and I am getting the error saying  'A JSONObject text must begin with '{' '

below is my code:

```
RestAssured.given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .accept(ContentType.ANY)
                .body(true)
                .put(sUrl)
                .then().log().ifError()
                .statusCode(Matchers.greaterThanOrEqualTo(200))
                .statusCode(Matchers.lessThanOrEqualTo(299))
                .extract()
                .response();
```

Let me know if you are aware of any solution for this.

Comment: perhaps you need to return a  stringified JSON object.

Comment: @geocodezip I am not having any issues with service response. I am having trouble at setting the request body as true/false

Comment: A solitary primitive is not valid json. It must either be a map or an array of maps. Try `.body(Map.of("value", true)`

Comment: Maybe try providing 'true' as a String instead of a Boolean?

Comment: Please take screenshot of postman request.

Answer (score 1):

A solitary primitive is not valid json, which you have specified it is via `contentType(ContentType.JSON)`.

The body must either be an object/map or an array of objects/maps.

Try

```
.body(Map.of("value", true))
```

Comment: tried but no luck. turned out as a bad request